# Change the x3dom model with a button click

Tags: javascript, x3dom

I have two x3d files namely `1.x3d` and `12.x3d` and I want to use a button to load them onto the canvas but my code doesn't seem to work . I see the loading icon in the top left but the model doesn't change .

Here is my code  : -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8'></meta>
      <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://www.x3dom.org/x3dom/release/x3dom.css'></link>
      <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.x3dom.org/x3dom/release/x3dom.js'></script>


      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
          $("button").click(function(){
           $("x3d > scene > inline").attr("url", "1.x3d");
          });
         });
      </script>

    </head>
   <body>

      <button> Click to Change Background </button>

      <x3d id='someUniqueId' showStat='false' showLog='false' x='0px' y='0px' width='400px' height='400px'>
       <scene>
          <inline id="myinline" url='12.x3d' ></inline>
       <scene>
      </x3d>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested it and it works as it should, but you can't test local.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/12.x3d. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: I have it on a webserver  : - http://mytestsite.webatu.com/inline.html . When I click the change button the loading icon spins for a second and then loads the same model.